# Error rendering data with Javascript / KendoUI autocomplete - Object #<Object> has no method 'slice' - how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, slice

I am following the [Using Kendo UI with MVC4 WebAPI OData and EF](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-10-25/using_kendo_ui_with_mvc4_webapi_odata_and_ef.aspx) article.  After installing KendoUI and making sure all references are set, I type in three characters, and get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'slice'

**Root of the Problem**

To save reading through the updates: Through debugging I found that the issue is that JS is expecting to parse an array, where it isn't available in the data - at the root.  In the data hierarchy, it's one level in.

**Original Problem**

I cleaned up kendo.web.min.js and the error is occuring around line 3498:

```
success: function (n) {
     var i = this,
         r = i.options;
     return i.trigger(wt, {
         response: n,
         type: "read"
     }), n = i.reader.parse(n), i._handleCustomErrors(n) ? (i._dequeueRequest(), t) : (i._pristine = et(n) ? e.extend(!0, {}, n) : n.slice ? n.slice(0) : n, i._total = i.reader.total(n), i._aggregate && r.serverAggregates && (i._aggregateResult = i.reader.aggregates(n)), n = i._readData(n), i._pristineData = n.slice(0), i._data = i._observe(n), i._addRange(i._data), i._process(i._data), i._dequeueRequest(), t)
```

The Kendo UI widgets are loading just fine as well as the css:

```
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/appScripts.js"></script>
```

And I am seeing the same error both with using the Razor MVC helper/extension:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("userAutoComplete")                   // specifies the "id" attribute of the widget
    .DataTextField("USERNAME")
    .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Url("/api/user");
                })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);       // if true, the DataSource will not filter the data on the client
        }
    )
)
```

and through directly through JS:

```
/// <reference path="kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" />
/// <reference path="kendo/kendo.core.min.js" />
/// <reference path="kendo/kendo.autocomplete.min.js" />
/// <reference path="kendo/kendo.web.min.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    // load up KendoUI

    // gets data from /api/user
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/api/user"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#userSearch").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataTextField: "USERNAME",
        minLength: 3
    });

    $("#userSearch").on('input', function () {
        console.log($("#userSearch").val());
    });

}); // $(document).ready()
```

I'm sure this is something simple that I may be missing.  I have tried both with the web and all js files.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**-- UPDATE --**

The only real html missing from that content is the `<input id="userAutoComplete" />`

I created a brand new solution and a very simple view, based on one of the Kendo UI examples that gets JSON data from http://api.geonames.org, and getting the same error.

I thought that using the newest JS library (`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` may have been causing a problem so I tried the 1.7 lib.  Same issue:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.common.min.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.default.min.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.dataviz.min.css")">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.dataviz.min.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#autoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({
                minLength: 6,
                dataTextField: "title",
                filter: "contains",
                dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON",
                            data: {
                                q: function () {
                                    return $("#autoComplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
                                },
                                maxRows: 10,
                                username: "demo"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "geonames"
                    }
                }),
                change: function () {
                    this.dataSource.read();
                }
            })
        });

    </script>    


</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <input id="autoComplete"/>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**-- UPDATE --**

Using the code above, I went back and tried it again - it worked fine.  After trying several more times, I experienced the same issue.  This was due to the valid JSON data changing to the following:

```
{"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.","value":18}}
```

... which lead me to look at the formatting of the data coming from my API (looking at it in Fiddler:

Instead of:

JSON
---{... data...

it's

```
JSON
---$id=1
---$values
------{}
---------$id=2
---------CREATEDATETIME...
---------EMAIL=email@email.com
---------GROUPS
------------$id=...
------------$id=...
---------USERNAME=someusername
------{}
---------$id=4
.
.
.
```

So the error is caused by the array not being accessible where the it's expected - instead of the root, it's one level deep.

How do I get data binding to the one-level-deep rather than the root of the JSON object?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also post your HTML? Is #userSearch an <input> element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for this was to traverse the data hierarchy by describing the result format.

Since the array is contained in $values, I used the following data source/schema definition:

```
    // gets data from /api/user
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/api/user"
            }
        },
        schema: {                               // describe the result format
            data: function(data) {              // the data which the data source will be bound to is in the values field
                console.log(data.$values);
                return data.$values;
            }
        }
    });
```

One thing that would be nice is to be able to add a data schema type in the Razor helper - which [doesn't seem to be supported at this time](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/combobox/setting-the-datasourceschema-attribute-of-the-datasource-in-a-kendo-combobox-in-razor-syntax.aspx#Xh73ROoZlEWDJVMzYnKr4Q).

Thus, the following still would not work:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
        .Name("userAutoComplete")                   // specifies the "id" attribute of the widget
        .Filter("startswith")
        .Placeholder("Type user name...")
        .DataTextField("USERNAME")
        .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source:
                    source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Url("/api/user");
                        })
                        .ServerFiltering(true);       // if true, the DataSource will not filter the data on the client

            }
        )
)
```

Answer (score 29):

I had the same error with a ComboBox that I was using as an autocomplete.  In my controller, the return statement was

```
return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(dataSourceRequest), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

which I changed to

```
return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

This provided the array at the root level instead of one level deep for me.

Comment: In my case I'm using OData, and implemented it like this: http://www.whatsinyourlunch.com/odata-kendo-ui-entity-framework-webapi/ - so the return type is either IEnumerable or IQueryable.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read:
            {
                url: "api/dashboard"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            **data: function (data)
            {
                return [data];
            }**
        }
    });
```

My response wasn't an array, i was returning from the server a response object like this:

```
{"Field1":0,"Field2":0,"Field3":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks "brittongr"...that worked for me too. but in my case it is not right, I was building a chart, a chart need an array of course, so instead of altering the schema by converting my Json data to an array I just returned from my action a list having one element. Something like this below.

```
Random rand = new Random();

int numIterations = 0;

numIterations = rand.Next(1, 1200);

List aux = new List&lt;graphicDataItem&gt;();

aux.Add(new graphicDataItem { ColumnTotal = 1200, ColumnActives = numIterations, ColumnInactives = 1200 - numIterations, ColumnApprovedByMembers = 250, ColumnApprovedByAssoc = 300, XAxisData = DateTime.Now.Year });

return Json(aux, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I have "graphicDataItem" type defined on my Entities folder, but is easy to get by looking at the way it is instantiated within the code.

Answer (score 0):

i change for this, and this work for me:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
 .Name("productAutoComplete") //The name of the autocomplete is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
  .DataTextField("myfield") //Specifies which property of the Product to be used by the autocomplete.
 .DataSource(source =>
 {
    source.Custom()
    .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
    .Transport(transport=>
    {
        transport.Read("MyAction", "Control");
    })
    .Schema(schema=>schema.Data("Data").Total("Total"))

    .ServerFiltering(true); //If true the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
})
```

)