# "Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function" while passing json data to view in "orchard"

Tags: javascript, json

```
public ActionResult Grouping()
        {
            return View();
        }

public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string text)
        {


            var result = _auto.Table.ToList().Where(s => s.Charactres.Contains(text));

            return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }

view code:`enter code here`




@model IEnumerable<Autocomplete.Models.Autocomplete>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Grouping";
}

<h2>Grouping</h2>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Modules/Autocomplete/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1119/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Modules/Autocomplete/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Modules/Autocomplete/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Modules/Autocomplete/Content/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Modules/Autocomplete/Content/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Modules/Autocomplete/Content/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Modules/Autocomplete/Content/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Modules/Autocomplete/Content/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="demo-section">
    <h4>Customers</h4>

    @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
              .Name("data")
              .DataTextField("ContactName")
              .Filter("contains")
              .MinLength(3)
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
              .Placeholder("Type a customer name")
              .DataSource(source => source
                  .Custom()
                  //.Group(g => g.Add("Country", typeof(string)))
                  .Transport(transport => transport
                    .Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("Read", "AutoComplete")
                            .Data("onAdditionalData");
                    }))
                .ServerFiltering(true))
    )
</div>
<script>
    function onAdditionalData() {
        return {
            text: $("#data").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try returning the result from the controller method without using ToDataSourceResult() method. This appears to send down the data without wrapping the array that client javascript looks for, inside an object.

So your controller return statement would look something like this:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I got this solution actually from another stackoverflow answer:
[Error rendering data with Javascript / KendoUI autocomplete - Object #<Object> has no method 'slice' - how to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836235/error-rendering-data-with-javascript-kendoui-autocomplete-object-object-h#18259952)

This solution worked for me.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was define the model (schema) to be the same as the data received.

In my case (ASP.NET MVC) I set a custom DataSource with the correct schema:

```
.DataTextField("description")
.DataValueField("name")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Custom()
    .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
    .ServerPaging(false)
    .ServerSorting(false)
    .ServerFiltering(false)
    .Transport(transport => transport
        .Read(read => read.Action("Get_Users", "User"))
    )
    .Schema(schema => schema
        .Data("Data")
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id("description");
            model.Field("name", typeof(string));
        })
    )
)
```

References:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/uncaught-typeerror-e-slice-is-not-a-function-on-data-fetch

[Error rendering data with Javascript / KendoUI autocomplete - Object #<Object> has no method 'slice' - how to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836235/error-rendering-data-with-javascript-kendoui-autocomplete-object-object-h#18259952)

Answer (score 0):

This following change worked for me, added schema after `dataSource` for `kendoGrid`:

```
schema: {
            data: "data"
        },
```